# Type error: unhashable type 'list' while selecting subset from specific columns pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

I have a dataframe that has about 20 columns and I am trying to get a subset of the dataframe by selecting only some specific columns about 6. My line of code is:

```
df3_query = df3[['Cont NUMBER'],['PL NUMBER'],['NAME'],['LOAN COUNT'],['SCORE    MINIMUM'],['COUNT PERCENT']]
```

I am getting an error as

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

May I know the reason in which why I get this error? Also I would like to select only those columns from the df3 dataframe. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: list is not hashable, Python need immutable data for hashing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to write your column names in one list not as list of lists:

```
df3_query = df3[['Cont NUMBER', 'PL NUMBER', 'NAME', 'LOAN COUNT', 'SCORE    MINIMUM', 'COUNT PERCENT']]
```

From [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#basics):

> You can pass a list of columns to `[]` to select columns in that order.
>   If a column is not contained in the DataFrame, an exception will be
>   raised. Multiple columns can also be set in this manner