# Trying to find Mean returns for following stocks from yahoo finance

Tags: python

```
tickers = ['BIOCON.NS', 'HDFCBANK.NS', 'RELIANCE.NS', 'RADICO.NS', 'LTI.NS', 'TCS.NS', 'DRREDDY.NS','BAJFINANCE.NS']

pfolio_data = pd.DataFrame()

for t in tickers:
    pfolio_data[t] = wb.DataReader(t, data_source='yahoo', start ='2017-1-1')['Adj Close']

pfolio_data_returns= (pfolio_data/pfolio_data.shift(1))-1
pfolio_data_returns

pfolio_data_returns[[[[[[[['BIOCON.NS', 'HDFCBANK.NS', 'RELIANCE.NS', 'RADICO.NS', 'LTI.NS', 'TCS.NS', 'DRREDDY.NS','BAJFINANCE.NS']]]]]]]].mean()
```

the last code shows me error -

```
unhashable type: 'list'
```

how should i go ahead with it ?

Answer (score 0):

What does the data in pfolio_data_returns look like ?
Maybe this is what you are looking for:
[Type error: unhashable type 'list' while selecting subset from specific columns pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34923728/type-error-unhashable-type-list-while-selecting-subset-from-specific-columns)

Answer (score 0):

There are too many opening/closing brackets. The following works:

`pfolio_data_returns[['BIOCON.NS', 'HDFCBANK.NS', 'RELIANCE.NS', 'RADICO.NS', 'LTI.NS', 'TCS.NS', 'DRREDDY.NS','BAJFINANCE.NS']].mean()`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as wb

tickers = ['BIOCON.NS', 'HDFCBANK.NS', 'RELIANCE.NS', 'RADICO.NS', 'LTI.NS', 'TCS.NS', 'DRREDDY.NS','BAJFINANCE.NS']
data = {ticker: wb.DataReader(ticker, data_source='yahoo', start ='2017-1-1')['Adj Close'] for ticker in tickers}
df_raw = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_returns = (
    df_raw
    .apply(lambda df: df/df.shift(1)-1)
)

df_returns.mean()

Out[28]: 
BIOCON.NS        0.001252
HDFCBANK.NS      0.000694
RELIANCE.NS      0.001477
RADICO.NS        0.001759
LTI.NS           0.001306
TCS.NS           0.000831
DRREDDY.NS       0.000503
BAJFINANCE.NS    0.001425
dtype: float64
```

I changed the way you create your dataframe. Looks a lot cleaner with a dictionary comprehension. `df_raw` contains raw data, `df_returns` computes the returns and the following `.mean()` statement computes the mean of each column.